# C Complex Numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, c99, complex-numbers

The following code compiles and runs just fine in C (at least according to 'gcc -std=gnu99'), but it fails to compile under C++, giving "line 5: error: cannot convert 'double' to 'double **complex**' in initialization".  Does anybody know why?

```
#include "/usr/include/complex.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  double complex a = 3;  // ERROR ON THIS LINE
  printf("%lf\n", creal(a));
  return 0;
}
```

I realize there is another way of doing complex numbers in C++, but I have to use C complex numbers in C++, because that is how the legacy code I was given does things.  Thanks if you can help!

Comment: But really, _why_ don't you want to use [`std::complex<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: FTR, `-std=gnu99` is not really the flag you want for **C**. That's "C with stuff GNU thought would be a good idea, but whether it is or not is up for interpretation". `-std=c99` is desirable if you want **C**.

Comment: ildjarn:  Unfortunately, the library I am working with uses C99 complex numbers in C++.  It does not seem wise to start a project this way, but this is the code I have to work with.  Martinho:  that's true.  I should have done the test with -std=c99

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the C keyword for complex: _Complex.  C++ uses complex as a (template) class.
I'm not sure where creal is or I would uncomment that.

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  double _Complex a = 3.0 + 0.0I;  // DECLARATION WORKS NOW - NOTE ASSIGNMENT MUST HAVE IMAG PART
  //printf("%lf\n", creal(a));
  return 0;
}
```

This works in gcc (I compiled with g++).  I got a warning about deprecated .h headers.

[Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2007-02/msg00161.html) is a link to an email trail showing nonstandard compatibility with C++ and C with complex numbers.  C++11 requires layout compatibility of C++ complexes with C _Complexes.

I'm currently investigating creal, etc. in C++.  I'm not finding anything in the standard.  Since there seems to be some effort to provide some source compatibility between C++ and C then creal, cpow, etc. might make a nice addition to TR2 the library proposals.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!   From what you said, I was able to get the solution.  Stack Overflow is not allowing me to post the solution yet, but it's that you have to add the imaginary part to the assignment.

Comment: As of this comments writing date/time, the above code produces a compiler error, `unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator"" I`, a newer `g++` version 4.8.x. Most likely the newer `g++` version is more standards compliant and so errors out on this syntax. I also tried the `_Complex_I` but that did not compile either on `g++`.

Comment: You can compile the code if you don't try to initialize... or set the variable. Which means your ability to use c style complex datatypes with a c++ compiler is... limited. If you want to use complex numeric processing in C++, I think the recommended solution is to use `std::complex<>`. If you are forced to use C code, then you are forced to use C99's complex types and functionality presented by `<complex.h>`. --> or to put it another way just read @StephenCanon's answer :) (i.e. use `std::complex`).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith  I agree that std::complex is by far preferable.  The OP was concerned about compiling C code with C++.  The initialization can be recovered by defining a capital 'I' literal operator.  (You'll get warns about missing underscore in user-space literal op.) Also note that `std::complex<double> z; static_cast<double(&)[2]>(z)` is a requirement for std::complex to overlap with other language's complex. Ugly but true.

Comment: I added the correct std reference and syntax as a comment to @StephenCanon's answer below.

Answer (score 20):

A C++ compiler could choose to support the `_Complex` keyword as an extension (and a few do), but that isn't portable.  If you want to have a portable C++ solution, you need to use the C++ std::complex templates, unfortunately.

The good news is that C++ std::complex numbers are guaranteed to be compatible with C complex numbers (in the sense that a pointer to one can always be converted to a pointer to the other, and the right thing will happen), which means that if you need to interoperate with a C library that expects C complex values, you won't have any trouble.

C11:

> Each complex type has the same representation and alignment requirements as an array type containing exactly two elements of the corresponding real type; the first element is equal to the real part, and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex number.

C++11:

> If `z` is an lvalue expression of type cv `std::complex<T>` then:
>
> — the expression `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)` shall be well-formed,
>
> — `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` shall designate the real part of `z`, and
>
> — `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `z`.

Comment: Where is that guarantee ("C++ std::complex numbers are guaranteed to be compatible with C99 complex numbers")?  The response below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10540288/2189128) cites a non-canonical source (Wikipedia) that say the opposite.

Comment: @Jeff: The wikipedia link doesn't actually contradict my claim; they are different types, but are guaranteed to have the same memory layout and alignment requirements.  I added the appropriate references to my answer.

Comment: The Chapter and verse on this is "29.5 Complex numbers [complex.numbers]" note 4: If `z` is an lvalue expr of type cv `complex<T>` then: the expr `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)` , `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[0]` is the real part of `z`, and `reinterpret_cast<cv T(&)[2]>(z)[1]` is the imag part of `z`.
, if `a` is an expr of type cv `complex<T>*` and the expr `a[i]` is well-defined for an integer
expr `i`, then: `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i]` shall designate the real part of `a[i]`, and `reinterpret_cast<cv T*>(a)[2*i + 1]` shall designate the imaginary part of `a[i]`.

Answer (score 9):

[Compatibility of C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++)

> Several additions of C99 are not supported in C++ or conflict with C++ features, such as variadic macros, compound literals, designated initializers, variable-length arrays, and **native complex-number types**. The long long int datatype and restrict qualifier defined in C99 are not included in the current C++ standard, but some compilers such as the GNU Compiler Collection[4] provide them as an extension. The long long datatype along with variadic templates, with which some functionality of variadic macros can be achieved, are present in the new C++ standard, C++11. On the other hand, C99 has reduced some other incompatibilities by incorporating C++ features such as // comments and mixed declarations and code.